How do you solve for x in the equation $(1+1/x)^{ 6x}=a$
I would assume that it uses the Lambert W function in some way, but I cannot figure out a way to transform it into a form where W(x) would be useful
So far, I have not been able to get very far past the first obvious step of taking the 6th root for both sides, and then substituting $a^{1/6}=b$ yielding the following:
$$(1+1/x)^x=b$$
From here however, I cannot think of a way to solve it. I tried to generalize the binomial series to a variable value of x, but I have a feeling that that is not possible at all.
It is also worth noting that specifically, I am interested in $a=π^4+π^5$, however a general solution to a would be nice

The only way to solve it is numerically. Getting better and better estimates.

Even the simpler equation, $x^x=b$ only has a closed form because we invented a function which is really close to just defining the inverse of $x^x.$ But that function, the Lambert W function, won't help here because of the $+1/x.$

Interestingly, $(\pi^4+\pi^5)^{1/6}$ is very close to $e.$ The difference is about $2\cdot10^{-8}.$

@ThomasAndrews the fact that (π^4+π^5)^1/6 is very close to e is how I initially came up with this problem. $π^4+π^5$ is very close to, but slightly less than $e^6$, and since I know e is the limit of $(1+1/x)^x$ as x approaches infinity, I asked myself “when does the value of (1+1/x)^(6x)= $π^4+π^5$?”

Ah, you wrote $(x+1/x)^x$ originally, didn't notice the change.

@ThomasAndrews Yeah sorry, only realized once I started writing out the limit definition of $e.$

I'm up to the step of $x$=$1$$/$$($$e$^($ln$$(a)$$/$$6x$)$-$$1$$)$, maybe that could help?

The original $(x+\frac1x)^x=b$ was harder to solve than $(1+\frac1x)^x=b$ which does have a solution with $W(x)$

It does? I'm not seeing it. @ТymaGaidash

@ThomasAndrews You can try setting it up as  $(1+\frac1x)^x=b\iff b^\frac1x-\frac1x=1$ and use How to solve $a^x + bx = c$?. Do you see it now?

EDIT: I took the time to make the calculations more calmly and got better estimates (and proofs).
Taking the natural logarithm (assuming positive $a$) and substituting $r=1/x$ we get
$$ \ln(1+r) / r = c, $$
where $c = \ln(a)/6$. Expanding the logarithm we have
$$c=1-\frac{r}{2}+\frac{r^2}{3}+ \ldots$$
Our goal is to find an approximation of the inverse function, e.g. to express $r$ as a function of $c$. It turns out that for $c \approx 1$, this is much easier. Let us substitute $c = 1-\delta$. We get
$$ 1- \delta = 1-\frac{r}{2}+\frac{r^2}{3}+ \ldots$$
$$ \delta = \frac{r}{2} - \frac{r^2}{3} +  \ldots $$
It is easy to see that $r:= r(\delta)$, as a function of $\delta$, is still smooth. Let's compute the first terms of its taylor expansion. Firstly, note that $r(0)=0$, as you can see from the original equation
$$ \frac{\ln(1+r(0))}{r(0)} = 1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \ln(1+r(0)) = r(0) $$
Let's set
$$r(\delta) = a_1 \delta + a_2 \delta^2 + O(\delta^3) $$
The constant term is zero because of $r(0) = 0$. Substituting the expression for $r$ in the expansion above, we get
$$ \delta = \frac{r(\delta)}{2} - \frac{r(\delta)^2}{3}  + O(\delta^3) = $$
$$ = \frac{a_1 \delta + a_2 \delta^2 + O(\delta^3)}{2} - \frac{(a_1 \delta + a_2 \delta^2)^2 + O(\delta^3)}{3} $$
$$ = \frac{a_1}{2} \delta + \left ( \frac{a_2}{2} - \frac{a_1^2}{3}  \right ) \delta^2 + O(\delta^3) $$
From which we get
$$ \left \{ \begin{array}{ll}
1 & = \frac{a_1}{2} \\
 0 &= \frac{a_2}{2} - \frac{a_1^2}{3} 
\end{array} \right . $$
The first equation yields $a_1 = 2$. Substituting into the second gives $a_2 = 8/3$. For the sake of curiosity, you can compute that  $a_3 = \frac{28}{9}$ with a similar method. Notice how fundamental has been for the sequence to have constant term equal to zero, otherwise all the terms of the expansion would have contributed to a single $\delta^k$ coefficient (think about it).
Putting everything together, we get the approximated formula for $x$:
$$ x = \frac{1}{r} \approx \frac{1}{2 \delta + \frac{8}{3} \delta^2 } = \frac{1}{2(1-c) + \frac{8}{3} (1-c)^2 } $$
In the case of interest, we have
$$ 1-c = 7.3013511117287530664 \cdot 10^{-9} $$
So that
$$ x \approx \frac{1}{ 1.4602702223457506133 \cdot 10^{-8} + 1.4215927481798052892\cdot 10^{-16}} = $$
$$ = \boxed{68,480,475.391,635,67...}$$
And we managed to find quite a lot of digits of the solution! I kept only 16 digits, that I am sure won't be modified by the subsequent terms of the expansion. Indeed, use a calculator to compute $x \ln(1+\frac{1}{x})$ in this value. You will get a difference of $\approx -3\cdot 10^{-23}$ with the actual value of $c$ (this should be zero on most precision calculators, that operate at 14 digits).
To get a precise estimate of the error, one should compute the third derivative of the inverse function with formulas akin to
$$ (f^{-1}(t) )' = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(t))} $$
and bound it for $\delta$ between $0$ and the actual value we are looking at. This, together with the Lagrange form of the remainder, furnishes an exact estimate of the error in our taylor expansion. Note though that $r'''(0) = 28/9$ as I mentioned, and I doubt that the estimate in an neighborhood of zero can be bigger than $10^{8}...$
For more resources about computing inverse taylor expansion, see also:
https://randorithms.com/2021/08/31/Taylor-Series-Inverse.html

An more general equation (but equivalent) with two parameters $a$ and $b$ :
$$(1+1/x)^{ b\,x}=a \tag 1$$
$$b\,x\ln(1+1/x)=\ln(a) \tag 2$$
Change of unknown :
$$y=1+1/x \quad\implies\quad x=\frac{1}{y-1} \tag 3$$
From (2) and (3) :
$$\frac{b}{y-1}\ln(y)=\ln(a) \tag 4$$
$$\ln(y)=y\frac{\ln(a)}{b}-\frac{\ln(a)}{b} \tag 5$$
$$y=\exp(y\frac{\ln(a)}{b})\exp(-\frac{\ln(a)}{b})\tag 6$$
$$y\exp(-y\frac{\ln(a)}{b})=\exp(-\frac{\ln(a)}{b})$$
$$-y\frac{\ln(a)}{b}\exp(-y\frac{\ln(a)}{b})=-\frac{\ln(a)}{b}\exp(-\frac{\ln(a)}{b})\tag 7$$
$w=-y\frac{\ln(a)}{b}\quad;\quad X=-\frac{\ln(a)}{b}\exp(-\frac{\ln(a)}{b})=-\frac{\ln(a)}{b}a^{-b} \tag 8$
From (7) and (8) :
$$we^w=X \tag 9$$
Solving requires a special function : The Lambert W function. $w=W(X)$.
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html
$$-y\frac{\ln(a)}{b}=W\left(-\frac{\ln(a)}{b}a^{-b}\right)\tag {10}$$
$$y=-\frac{b}{\ln(a)}W\left(-\frac{\ln(a)}{b}a^{-b}\right) \tag{11}$$
With Eq.(3) the analytic solution of equation (1) is :
$$\boxed{x=\frac{1}{-\frac{b}{\ln(a)}W\left(-\frac{\ln(a)}{b}a^{-b}\right)-1}}\tag{12}$$
Take care : The notation $b$ above is not the notation $b$ in the question.
The numerical case interesting the OP is very particular :
$b=6$ and $a=\pi^4+\pi^5\simeq 403.4287758192838$
The argument of the LambertW function is $\simeq -0.367879441171442$ which is very close to $-1/e$.
LambertW$(-1/e)=-1.$
Thus the analytic solution Eq.(12) is reduced to
$x\simeq\frac{1}{\frac{b}{\ln(a)}-1}\simeq 1.369609485598859*10^8$
Considering the approximation made all the digits are not guaranteed. A much more accurate numerical calculus would be required.
